# How to connect a fast recovery diode with 3 pins?

Tags: diodes, fuses, connect

I have a fast recovery diode, part number [D30FD60K](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fme/shindengen/J532_D30FD60K.pdf), I would like to know how I have to connect it. The diode will be used as the return path in parallel with a fuse. Like shown in the diagram.

Pin 3 will go to the switch, but I don't know how to connect 1 and 2. And why is a NC on pin 1? Is that normally closed, how does it open?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2qyJ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: NC means Not Connected.

Comment: In a typical D252 package either pins 1 and 3 are connected, or there is another diode going in opposite direction. In both cases I would recommend to  connect 1 and 3 in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That diode has four pins.

You connect it as shown in the diagram in the datasheet:

[image]

Pin 1 is not connected (NC) electrically.  Place a pad to mount it.  It is only there for mechanical purposes.

Pin 2 is a stub.  You cannot place a pad for it.  It is electrically connected to pin 4 (the large tab on the back of the part.)

Pin 3 is the anode.  It goes to the switch in your circuit.

Pin 4 is the tab on the back.  It is the cathode.  You connect it to the power supply in your circuit.